# Twilio speech recognition C# package resolving <gather> missing attributes

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml, speech-recognition-api

I want to use Twilio  TwiML.Gather for speech recognition and my current version is missing the "input" and "hints" (as well as several other) attributes . I was wondering if there is a new package available that has resolved these issues.If not, how can I manually add them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio .NET library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) has supported attributes such as `input` and `hint` at least since version 5.8.0. You can [update to the latest version, 5.13.0, from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/5.13.0).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you , I downloaded the new package and it's working. Just one more question. On the documentation says that value for 'input' attribute for both speech and digit is  "dtmf speech"  but code gives me an error:

Comment: var gather = new Gather(input: "speech dtmf", timeout: 4 , action: new Uri("MainMenu"), numDigits: 1);